# How can I run my Discord bot that updates from an API without hitting Discord's 1,000 connection maximum?

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py, bots

I built a bot that updates the name of the bot to a price in Python. Likewise, the status of the bot updates to a different price as well. The bot works as intended for a bit of time, but then I receive the following message from Discord:

> It appears your bot, "MY BOT NAME", has connected to Discord more than 1000 times within a short time period. Since this kind of behavior is usually a result of a bug we have gone ahead and reset your bot's token.

My bot runs every 15 seconds, from a shell script, on a linux server, that also kills the last process which was run before it. I kill the preceding process so they don't eat up my memory and crash my server.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import json
import emoji
import sys
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

url = 'URL FOR THE API'
price = requests.get(url)

rapid_gprice = price.json()['data']['price1']
standardp = price.json()['data']['price2']

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = client.get_guild(MY GUILD ID)
    me = guild.me
    await me.edit(nick=standardp)
    activity = discord.Game(name=rapid_gprice)
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)

client.run('MY TOKEN')
```

I'm fairly certain I need to use some sort of function inside my Python script that loops through the price api and updates the Discord bot accordingly, only having to run the Python script once.

I'm happy to provide any additional information you may need. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving my issue. It's probably code overkill but it works. Feel free to help me alter it to make it more efficient:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import aiohttp
import json
import asyncio
import discord

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

url = 'THE API LINK I''M USING'

async def getPrice1():
   async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
      response = await resp.json()
      price1 = response['data']['priceZYX']
      return price1

async def getPrice2():
   async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
      response = await resp.json()
      price2 = response['data']['priceXYZ']
      return price2

@tasks.loop(seconds=7)
async def change_nick(guild):
    nick = await getPrice1()
    await guild.me.edit(nick=nick)
    activity = discord.Game(name=await getPrice2())
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=activity)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    guild = client.get_guild(MY GUILD ID)
    change_nick.start(guild)
```

Answer (score 3):

Running your script every 15 seconds is a really bad idea, there's an build-in discord.py extension called tasks, it lets you run background tasks, hence the name.

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=15)
async def change_nick(guild):
    nick = # Get the nick here
    await guild.me.edit(nick=nick)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    guild = client.get_guild(MY GUILD ID)
    change_nick.start(guild)
```

Also I see that you're using `requests`, which is a blocking library, I'd suggest you using [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) instead

Take a look at the [tasks introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Łukasz. I'm fairly new to Python, as well as Discord. The idea to re-run the shell script every 15 seconds was to have the price update that often as well [,as well as not having an entirely complete understanding of how bots function]. I believe the api I use updates prices every 6 seconds, but I didn't need to go to that extent.

Comment: Alright, you can change the interval in the decorator to 6 seconds as the ratelimit for changing a users nick is 1 request per second per guild so the ratelimit is not a problem. Also remember to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: I've accepted your answer as so, but I'm still having issues with this. Even I run just the code you provided above with my original "request"  on the url, the loop doesn't seem to be refreshing the name of the bot every 15 seconds.

Comment: That's not the issue with the code, either your website doesn't provide the updated data or you're not getting the updated nick. There's nothing wrong with my code, tried it with creating a random string as the nick and it works flawlessly

Comment: Though I appreciate your submission because it did help me greatly, it is an incomplete answer, and thus cannot be *the* "answer".

Comment: I think it's pretty much the complete answer, the only thing left to implement is making the request and getting the new nick. I'm not gonna code your whole "nick changing system" for you, I've answered your question and pretty much coded everything you need apart from getting the nick (which you already know how to get it as it was in your question, the only thing you were supposed to do it copy and paste it)

Answer (score 0):

I got an error trying to implement the pricedata (from url) to my bot's username.
*The error: discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In nick: Could not interpret "(the live price)" as string.*

If you have the same problem (and using discord rewrite), make sure to label (nick=nick) as a string:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=15)
async def change_nick(guild):
   nick = await getPrice1()
   await guild.me.edit(nick=str(nick))
```

*PS: Im fairly new to coding so please correct me if im wrong, it worked for me. Also thanks for this posts it helped me alot making my bot.*